# Max Value within Dynamic Time Windows Returned From pct_change

Tags: python, pandas

After running pct_change on a dataframe it returns the following series:

```
2019-01-31 14:50:00+00:00    0.019148
2019-01-31 14:55:00+00:00    0.010169
2019-01-31 15:00:00+00:00    0.019267
2019-01-31 15:05:00+00:00    0.020533
2019-01-31 15:10:00+00:00    0.011643
2019-01-31 15:15:00+00:00    0.007947
2019-01-31 16:15:00+00:00    0.008298
2019-01-31 16:45:00+00:00    0.013067
2019-01-31 16:50:00+00:00    0.012477
2019-01-31 16:55:00+00:00    0.007143
2019-01-31 17:00:00+00:00    0.008201
2019-01-31 18:50:00+00:00    0.008156
2019-01-31 18:55:00+00:00    0.009464
2019-01-31 19:00:00+00:00    0.014694
2019-01-31 19:05:00+00:00    0.007839
2019-01-31 19:10:00+00:00    0.007829
```

How can I find the max value for each dynamic time window returned. So the result would be:

```
2019-01-31 15:05:00+00:00    0.020533
2019-01-31 16:45:00+00:00    0.013067
2019-01-31 19:00:00+00:00    0.014694
```

Doesn't have to be one operation. If I could split the series by each dynamic window then getting the max is trivial.

Comment: `for each dynamic time window` - Can you explain more?

Comment: Sure, overall the data has 5 minute ("5T") timestamps. I ran pct_change with freq=20T and then I sliced the results to only include rows where the percent change was above a certain level. The result above has dynamic windows i.e. groups of contiguous timestamps (2019-01-31 14:50:00+00:00 to 2019-01-31 15:15:00+00:00) is one group (2019-01-31 16:45:00+00:00 to 2019-01-31 17:00:00+00:00) is another. Looking for the max pct_change within each contagious group of timestamps which represents one sustained period of change.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution, seems like there are probably more efficient ways to do it though.

```
    def interval_windower(series):
        result_list = []
        last_ts = series.index[0]
        interval_window = 1
        for row in series.iteritems():
            if(row[0] - last_ts).seconds > 300:
                interval_window += 1
            result_list.append({"timestamp": row[0], "change": row[1], "interval_window": interval_window})
            last_ts = row[0]

        df = DataFrame.from_records(result_list)
        return df.loc[df.groupby("interval_window")["change"].idxmax()]
```

then

```
max_intervals = interval_windower(series)
```

returns

```
      change  interval_window                 timestamp
3   0.020533                1 2019-01-31 15:05:00+00:00
6   0.008298                2 2019-01-31 16:15:00+00:00
7   0.013067                3 2019-01-31 16:45:00+00:00
13  0.014694                4 2019-01-31 19:00:00+00:00
```